# What is the Ansible equivalent playbook for "lxc launch ubuntu: new-container"

Tags: ansible

What is the Ansible equivalent of playbook of `lxc launch ubuntu: new-container`.

I can successfully ping the machine on which I want to create the container, and when logged into that machine I can create a container without any problems. When I try to use the below playbooks however, I get the following results:

Attempt 1:

```
- hosts: node0
  tasks:
    - name: Create a started container
      lxd_container:
        name: mycontainer
        state: started
        profiles: ["default"]
```

Result:

```
# ansible-playbook play 

PLAY [node0] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [node0]

TASK [Create a started container] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [node0]: FAILED! => {"actions": [], "changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "unknown source type "}
    to retry, use: --limit @/root/play.retry

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
node0                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Attempt 2:

```
- hosts: node0
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - name: create a container
    connection: local
    become: false
    lxd_container:
      name: test
      state: started
      source:
        type: image
        mode: pull
        server: https://images.linuxcontainers.org
        protocol: lxd
        alias: "ubuntu/xenial/amd64"
      profiles: ["default"]
      wait_for_ipv4_addresses: false
      timeout: 600
```

Result:

```
# ansible-playbook play 

PLAY [node0] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [create a container] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [node0]: FAILED! => {"actions": [], "changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to change ownership of: /var/lib/lxd/containers/test/rootfs"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/root/play.retry

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
node0                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Attempt 3 seems to work however it seems to download a new image instead of using the one which already exists on the machine:

```
# An example for creating a Ubuntu container and install python
- hosts: node0
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Create a started container
      lxd_container:
        name: mycontainer
        state: started
        source:
          type: image
          mode: pull
          server: https://images.linuxcontainers.org
          protocol: lxd
          alias: ubuntu/xenial/amd64
        profiles: ["default"]
        wait_for_ipv4_addresses: true
        timeout: 600
```

How to write a playbook equivalent of `lxc launch ubuntu: new-container`?

Comment: Why do you use `connection: local`? It means to run commands on local ansible host.

Comment: I wasn't sure about that and I could not find any info on the connection in Ansible's Playbook documentation or Glossary. Where can more information be found about it?

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#non-ssh-connection-types

Comment: Thank you, I edited my inventory settings and it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from comments:

> Why do you use `connection: local`? It means to run commands on local ansible host.

You should connect to target host and execute `lxd_container` module there.